# Destroy a view during simulate memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am reading a book where there is a UITabBarController with two tabs. One **Time** tab and another **Hypnosis** tab. The **Time** tab shows a `TimeViewController`
and the **Hypnosis** tab shows a `HypnosisViewController`.

This is the implementation from the `TimeViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    NSLog(@"Unloading TimeViewController's subviews");
    timeLabel = nil;
}
```

The book says if I simulate a memory warning while I am on the **Hypnosis** tab,
I should see the log message I typed above. However, this does not happen.
Does anyone have any idea why? I am using iOS 6.1 simulator and the latest
Xcode (even though the book is about iOS 5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's deprecated in new versions, you should use;

```
didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

From Apple:

> In iOS 6, the viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods of UIViewController are now deprecated. If you were using these methods to release data, use the didReceiveMemoryWarning method instead. You can also use this method to release references to the view controller’s view if it is not being used. You would need to test that the view is not in a window before doing this.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the answer. Also one thing, in the same sample. Say I am on a Timer tab, and I simulate memory warning. The book says during this time the view of the other Tab (Hypnosis) should get destroyed. So, when I switch to the Hypnosis tab, I should see  a log message which I had in the viewDidLoad of HypnosysViewcontroller (since the view would be recreated) - but this does not happen. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: No idea, it could be that the behaviour is different in new versions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to new question in comments: Apparently this has changed as well. Off screen views are no longer automatically destroyed when a low memory warning is received. From http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=219&t=5111#p13862